# 10000 concurrent connection using Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

I wrote a Server(similar to one [here](http://adblogcat.com/asynchronous-java-nio-for-dummies/)) and [Client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473163/nio-client-giving-exception-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-no) using Java nio.

I am trying to achieve as many connections as possible.
From previous suggestions I slowed down the process of Client creation giving OS(Windows 8) enough time to handle the requests.

I ran the Client code on different machine so that Server has all available space for running.

When I try to create 10,000 connections around 8500 are getting connected and rest are refused for connection and the refusal of connection for clients(threads in client code) happens more which are created later (for loop in Client code ).

My CPU and Memory usage go drastically high.I profiled to see most(48% of total CPU consumption) is consumed by select method (rest mostly by gui events) . Is it due to so many clients ? also I saw some people complaining about this bug in JRE7 and suggesting to use JRE6 .

Memory Usage are 2000+ MB for `javaw.exe` processes.(I noticed 1 process which was using low memory but had major CPU usage ).Overall usage we around 98% when all 8500 or so clients were connected. The system hanged too for many times but continued to service.I saw Non-page pooled memory usage increased during the process from 178 MB to 310 MB (what is the max limit ?).Is it because when we write to sockets Non-page pooled memory is used ?

Can anybody please tell which limits I might be hitting so the 10,000 successful connections are not possible ?
(Socket per process limit ?)(Non-paged memory ?)(Backlog Queue again ?)
Tweaks that might be able to allow limits to be pushed ? (Windows machine)

I am using Windows 8 on a 4GB system.

`

```
public class Server implements Runnable  {

public final static String ADDRESS = "192.168.2.14";

public final static int PORT = 8511;

public final static long TIMEOUT = 10000;

public int clients;

ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

private ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;

private Selector selector;

private Map<SocketChannel,byte[]> dataTracking = new HashMap<SocketChannel, byte[]>();

public Server(){
    init();
}

private void init(){
    System.out.println("initializing server");

    if (selector != null) return;
    if (serverChannel != null) return;

    try {
        selector = Selector.open();
        serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(ADDRESS, PORT));
        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Now accepting connections...");
    try{
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

            int ready = selector.select();
            if(ready==0)
                continue;
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

            while (keys.hasNext()){
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()){
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()){
                    System.out.println("Accepting connection");
                    accept(key);
                }

                if (key.isWritable()){
                    System.out.println("Writing...");
                    write(key);
                }

                if (key.isReadable()){
                    System.out.println("Reading connection");
                    read(key);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        closeConnection();
    }

}

private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException{

    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    byte[] data = dataTracking.get(channel);
    dataTracking.remove(channel);
    **int count = channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
    if(count == 0)
    {
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        return;
    }
    else if(count > 0)
    {
        key.interestOps(0);
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);  
    }** 
}

private void closeConnection(){

    System.out.println("Closing server down");
    if (selector != null){
        try {
            selector.close();
            serverChannel.socket().close();
            serverChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException{
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    if(socketChannel == null)
    {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
     clients++;
    **//socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE|SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    SelectionKey skey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);**

    byte[] hello = new String("Hello from server").getBytes();
    dataTracking.put(socketChannel, hello);
}

private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException{
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    readBuffer.clear();
    int length;
    try {
        length = channel.read(readBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Reading problem, closing connection");
        System.out.println("No of clients :"+clients);
        key.cancel();
        channel.close();
        return;
    }
    if (length == -1){
        System.out.println("Nothing was there to be read, closing connection");
        channel.close();
        key.cancel();
        return;
    }

    readBuffer.flip();
    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    readBuffer.get(data, 0, length);
    String fromclient = new String(data,0,length,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Received: "+fromclient);
    String dat = fromclient+channel.getRemoteAddress();
    data= dat.getBytes();
    echo(key,data);
}

private void echo(SelectionKey key, byte[] data) throws IOException{
    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    dataTracking.put(socketChannel, data);
    **//key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    try
    {
        write(key);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem in echo"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Thread serv = new Thread(new Server());
    serv.start();
}
```

}

Comment: You are hitting the listen backlog queue limit. You need to make your server accept loop faster, or moderate your expectations.

Comment: @EJP 
I see you suggesting not to use separate threads for Reading/Writing here
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305386/java-nio-socketchannel-read-with-multithread)
So then how to make accept loop faster ?

Comment: What `accept()` loop would that be? How can I tell you how to make it faster when you haven't posted it? The listen backlog is specified when you call [`ServerSocket.bind(InetSocketAddress, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#bind-java.net.SocketAddress-int-), but the platform can adjust it up or down. The default was raised from 5 about 20 years ago.

Comment: Code that forms part of a question must be posted in the question.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for telling that  Please see I have put the code now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79404/discussion-between-cruxion-effux-and-ejp).

Comment: Why is a method that closes everything named `closeConnection()`?

Comment: @EJP

Its just that it was same in the code I copied.I will try to use better renaming.

Comment: @cruxioneffux You might want to remove the `System.out.println()` stuff from the loop as it's pretty slow!

Comment: @SvetlinZarev 
Ok will do but how much will that affect ?

Comment: I hope a lot, as it's a blocking call. You should use proper logging instead of this `println()`s

Comment: @SvetlinZarev : Won't the logging incur the cost of writing to a file ?

Comment: @cruxioneffux Yes, and no. Usually the logging frameworks write the messages asynchronously, so the calls to `logger.log()` will be very fast and will return immediately without waiting for the content to be flushed to a file/console. Also you can configure your logger to dump the logs to the console instead of a file.

Answer (score 2):

```
socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE|SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

This is incorrect usage. Your selector will spin, as `OP_WRITE` is almost always ready, except at the rare times when the socket send buffer is full. This is why you're not processing `OP_ACCEPT` as fast as you could. You're busy processing `OP_WRITE` at times when you have nothing to write.

The correct way to use `OP_WRITE` is as follows:

- Register a newly accepted channel for `OP_READ` only
- When you have something to write to the channel, just write it
- If that write returns zero, register the channel for `OP_WRITE`, save the `ByteBuffer` you were trying to write, and return to the select loop
- When `OP_WRITE` fires on the channel, call `write()` with the same buffer
- if that write succeeds and doesn't return zero, register `OP_READ` again, or at least remove `OP_WRITE` from the `interestOps`.

NB Closing a channel cancels its key. You don't need the cancel.

Comment: What if I use this :
<ul>
* I don't register for both Read and Write.

* As soon as I have something to write I update interest list with write.

- On next select I will get isWritable() true and reach my write function there I attempt to write if success-full (even partially) I remove write from interest list else I keep registering for Write ?

</ul>

Comment: 1)What If I need to reply to client when he connects i.e when I run accept(key) method then I need to register atleast once then I can remove it from interest list.    

    2)Your last point if that write succeeds and doesn't return zero, register OP_READ again, or at least remove `OP_WRITE` from the `interestOps`.  
Atleast ? Is there a difference ?

Comment: Nothing has changed. You still don't need to register `OP_WRITE` initially. Just *do the `write()` etc.* as above. A connected socket is almost always writable, again as per above, and it is certainly writable when first accepted or connected, because the socket send buffer is initially empty. Re last question, you may not be interested in the socket at all for a while (at least it's a theoretical possibility), so you might not want to register `OP_READ` ... but you *certainly* want to deregister `OP_WRITE.`

Comment: Now I tried what you said about not registering for `OP_WRITE`(see I have edited the original code between ** to represent changed code ) and as previously on Client side tried creating batches of 100 clients per 5 seconds and a total of 10000.Although now more clients were able to connect but not all around 9500 were able to connect.


What's wrong now.

Comment: The same thing that was always wrong. You're connecting faster than you're accepting. But you're close. The question now is whether you're running a realistic test. Are you really going to be acquiring new client connections at a flat-out rate?

Comment: Yes ! But how to be able to accept at faster rate(Now I even avoided spinning for `OP_WRITE`) ?.
100 clients per 5 seconds doesn't seem too high.
And I think for such simple server 10k connections are pretty low . Using java nio people are scaling but here I am not even able to get 10k clients connected.I think I was to be limited by hardware but I am here by code and deeply problemed.

Comment: There's a difference between connect *rate* and the *total* number of connections. I agree that 10,000 connections in total isn't too many, but you're not testing that: you're testing how *fast* you can accept connections. If you really can't accept 100 clients per 5 seconds there is certainly something seriously wrong, but this is the first mention of connections per unit time in the question, and it's a different question from the one you've been asking.

Comment: Please see my original Question(2nd line) I am trying to achieve maximum connections.I generated 100 clients per 5 seconds because the queue was failing to serve if I create all client threads very fast.
So why I am able to achieve just 10k connections ? As I asked in original question : What limits I am hitting ? or problem in code ?
I really thank you for constant support.

Comment: So today I tried creating batch of 50 clients per 5 seconds and the 10k clients were able to connect.

I think this means when higher load is there(9000+ clients) Server is not able to accept a batch of 100 clients (the queue must have filled and thread was not able to process accept ) .Now as you said we must accept faster ? Won't a new thread just to accept connections help ? If no what would help ? These no's are not much for NIO , what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @cruxioneffux were you able to find a solution for this? I am trying to create a server which can take upto 30K connections. I am able to reach 2500 connections but after that I start getting the "java.io.IOException: Broken pipe" exception on my client side.