# concurrent connection using Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

The general outline of the problem is   ClientSocketChannel with multithreading use CPU more than expected.
The general thing is ClientSocketChannel with multithreading.
OK, I should say that the question that I am going to ask is asked before in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571829/10000-concurrent-connection-using-java-nio?answertab=active#tab-top).

There is also other posts with the same answers. The reason that I mentioned it again is that I really cannot understand the answers as it is not obvious and I cannot adopt my code with them. I try to briefly explain the requirement to see if there is an answer that can cover whole requirements.

1. The write process should trigger with bytebuffer which fill in another thread
2. The system have to be conscious of either write or read operation, as any of them could happen first.
3. A way to prevent useless cpu running which seems that OP_write make it busy when it is not required.

ANSWER:

> The correct way to use OP_WRITE is as follows:
>
> Register a newly accepted channel for OP_READ only

So do we need just one channel with OP_READ operand or both (channel1 OP_READ, channel2 OP_READ | OP_WRITE)?

> When you have something to write to the channel, just write it

in which part of the code?

> If that write returns zero, register the channel for OP_WRITE, save the ByteBuffer you were trying to write, and return to the select loop
> When OP_WRITE fires on the channel, call write() with the same buffer
> if that write succeeds and doesn't return zero, register OP_READ again, or at least remove OP_WRITE from the interestOps.

"If that write returns zero" as far as my knowledge it means that no byte to write, so why should I register for OP_WRITE?

"save byte buffer": is it true to put this buffer as a third argument of register? something like below?

```
  channel.register(selector, operations, SharedBuffer);
```

Comment: Use quote formatting for text that is quoted.

Answer (score 1):

> The write process should trigger with bytebuffer which fill in another thread

Why? The other thread can do the actual write. You don't need to 'trigger' anything.

> The system have to be conscious of either write or read operation, as any of them could happen first.

No problem.

> A way to prevent useless cpu running which seems that OP_write make it busy when it is not required.

Correct. OP_WRITE is almost always ready, so using it when you don't have pending data to write *which has already failed* is just going to smoke the CPU.

> So do we need just one channel with OP_READ operand or both (channel1 OP_READ, channel2 OP_READ | OP_WRITE)?

You only need one channel.

> in which part of the code?

In the part that knows it has something to write.

> "If that write returns zero" as far as my knowledge it means that no byte to write,

No it doesn't. See the Javadoc. It means that nothing was *written*. If there was 'no byte to write' you wouldn't have called `write()` in the first place.

> so why should I register for OP_WRITE?

So you can be told when the channel becomes writable.

> "save byte buffer": is it true to put this buffer as a third argument of register? something like below?

Yes.

Comment: thank for your patient. seems it is at least the 3th time that you explain the same thing. I'm thinking about JAVA NIO without you ...

Comment: More lile the 3,00th actually.

Comment: Sorry that I am asking you this, but as there is some dark part in NIO, why you are not writing a book on this topic? I personally have read 2 books (of course not whole the book, but the relative part). but non of them gave me the things that they had to give.